# Windows Phone | Facebook Integration With Add an Account Option

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7

I am integrating facebook API with Facebook.dll.
I want autologin for facebook in my application if I already have added accounts in my Windows Phone. The "add account" option is available in Phone Settings.
So when user has already added facebook account, then I do not want user to login in my application.
How can I do this??????

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible with the current Windows Phone SDK.
Third-party apps don't have access to accounts information (for privacy reasons I suppose).